# Retrieve all JSON key's values from JSON without known structure

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I get JSON from some endpoint and I only know it will contain array called 'x', which can contain everything (another arrays, JSON properties etc.).

Now, I want to retrieve values from all keys and concatenate it into one string.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632398/how-do-i-get-all-the-fields-using-json-net) but when it encounters arrays of properties it gives me as it is, like this:

```
"test": {
      "test1": "tea",
      "test2": "tt",
      "foo": "",
      "bar": "48f7c3284ca0",
      "random": "Harry",
      "anything": "Potter"
    },
```

And I would like to retrieve from above just values and concatenate them into string like so:

"tea tt  48f7c3284ca0 Harry Potter".

In other words - I want to *foreach* every key from **generic** JSON and, if it doesn't have child, get it's value and keep *foreaching*.

Comment: Just enumerate properties values of  `test` node

Comment: You should provide a specific piece of JSON covering *all* kinds of expected input/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Flat(JToken token)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            // nested value types
            case JTokenType.Object:
            case JTokenType.Array:
            case JTokenType.Property:
                foreach (var item in token.Children().Select(Flat).SelectMany(x => x))
                    yield return item;
                break;
            default: // primitive values: int, string, float
                yield return token.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        JToken token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(File.ReadAllText("test.json"));
        foreach (var item in Flat(token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Here is the test output
https://ctrlv.cz/TvqP

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like (in case fields are primitive types):

```
            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{'test1':'tea','test2':'tt','foo':'','bar':'48f7c3284ca0','random':'Harry','anything':'Potter'}");

            List<string> resultValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(stuff))
            {
                resultValues.Add(prop.GetValue(stuff).ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd RegEx my way through the raw string:

```
(\s*:\s*"?)(\s*[\w\.]*)("?\s*)
```

Each match has the value in **Group 2**.

The demo is here (it also provides the breakdown of the regex): https://regex101.com/r/Nh7bTS/

The JSON used in the demo is the following:

```
{
  test: {
    "emptystr": "",
    "str": "p",
    "num": 6,
    "obj": {
      "k20": {
        "k200": "uz"
      }
    },
    "arr": [ 2, 3, 4 ],
    "str1": "  asd",
    "num1": 0.33445,
  }
}
```

Depth doesn't matter, as long as the input is valid JSON.

The list of matches must be filtered to exclude all the matches where Group 1 is equal to `:`  (it means the value is neither a string nor a number).

Comment: Regex sounds great, but in the demo you have provided, not all values are matched. For example, obj.k20.k200 has "uz" value and it doesn't match:/

Comment: That's a significantly different requirement from the question. Let's see...

Comment: Thank you Alex, although I choose other answer, your is great also.